# How prove $ \frac{\cos x\cos y-4}{\cos x+\cos y-4}\le1+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\frac{x+y}{\cos x+\cos y-4}) $?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

For any $x,y\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ , how prove the inequality
$\frac{\cos x\cos y-4}{\cos x+\cos y-4}\le1+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\frac{x+y}{\cos x+\cos y-4})$?

Answer (score 0):

hint:

$\cos{X} \ge -\dfrac{X}{\pi}+\dfrac{1}{2}$(concave)

$x+y \le \pi$

you will find  to prove

$\cos{x}+\cos{y}-\cos{x}\cos{y} \le 2$

Comment: If $\cos x\cos y\geq 0$ its true. Let $\cos x\cos y<0$ and $\cos y<0$. So
$\cos x+\cos y-\cos x\cos y\leq \cos x-\cos x\cos y\leq 2$